# Selenium: How do I check the src attribute of an image?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, frontend

I'm trying to check the value of the `src` attribute for this image (highlighted in blue):

[image]

This is what I'm trying (not working):

```
visual = col_12_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name('visual')
left_text_img = visual.find_element_by_css_selector('div.col-sm-6:first-of-type')
left_img = left_text_img.find_element_by_tag_name('img')

#this line below fails
left_img[contains(@src,'../../static/images/databytes/colors/frame-0164.jpg')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
left_img[contains(@src,'../../static/images/databytes/colors/frame-0164.jpg')]
```

Is trying to use an ***XPATH*** as an index.

you would need to use `find_element` like so:

```
left_img.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@src, '../../static/images/databytes/colors/frame-0164.jpg')]")
```

I would recommend a more direct path of finding this element though:

```
direct_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='visual']/div[@class='col-sm-6']//img[@class='color-frame' and contains(@src, 'frame-0164.jpg')]")
```

If you want to get the element and **then** check it's `src` attribute, try this:

```
direct_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='visual']/div[@class='col-sm-6']//img[@class='color-frame']")
src_attribute = direct_path.get_attribute('src')
```

***SIDENOTE***: Based on your error message in the comments, you are running on an old chromedriver **2.35** which does not support your current version of Chrome **67**, please go [HERE](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) to update your **chromedriver** as well. Recommended for build 67 is current chromedriver **2.40**.

Comment: I'm getting this error; `global name 'driver' is not defined`   So how do I define 'driver'? FYI- this is at the top of my script `from selenium.webdriver import Chrome`

Comment: whatever you set your `driver = Chrome()` to is the ***driver***.

Comment: so if you use `browser = Chrome()`, browser would be the driver, or `chrome = Chrome()`, chrome would be the driver.

Comment: ok, thats added. Unfortunately I'm still getting this error:  `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@class='visual']/div[@class='col-sm-6']/img[@class='color-frame' and contains(@src, 'frame-0164.jpg')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)`

Comment: Try the update path, I may have had the xpath wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :  [you can get the **src** attribute from the DOM like this and it's always good to use WebDriverWait]

```
img = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.color-squares.squares-20+img')))  
source = img.get_attribute("src")  
print(source)
```

Note that you will have to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In case you are looking for **xpath** , that would be :

```
//div[contains(@class,'color-squares squares-20')]/following-sibling::img
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the XPath of the img element

```
//img[@class='color-frame'][contains(@src,'frame-0164.jpg')]
```